# Set Windows IP from Qt application

Tags: c++, windows, powershell, qt, cmd

I'm exploring the possibility of setting windows ip from a Qt5 application and the following seems to work

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QThread>
#include <QProcess>
#include <QFile>
#include <QDir>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QString filename = "file";

    auto preparescript = [](QString cmd, QString filename) {
        QFile f(filename+".bat");
        if (!f.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text)) return;
        QTextStream out(&f);

        out << QString("cd \"%1\"\n").arg(QDir::toNativeSeparators(QDir::currentPath()));
        out << cmd;
    };

    auto name  = "Ethernet";
    auto ip  = "192.168.1.7";
    auto mask  = "255.255.255.0";
    auto gateway  = "192.168.1.1";
    auto cmd = QString("netsh interface ip set address name=\"%1\" static %2 %3\n").arg(name,
                                                                                        ip,
                                                                                        mask,
                                                                                        gateway);

    preparescript(cmd, filename);

    QProcess p;
    p.start("cmd.exe", {"/C", QString("Powershell Start %1 -Verb Runas").arg(filename+".bat")});

    if (!p.waitForFinished())
        return -1;

    return a.exec();
}
```

However the terminal window where the script gets executed pops up for a split of a second which dims the elegance of this solution.

1. How can I hide the terminal?
2. How to do it without creating the .bat file?
3. Are there other, more elegant, solutions for setting windows ip from a Qt application?

Comment: There will be a Win32 function that does this. A quick google for *win32 set ipaddress* should pop up some good research avenues.

Comment: [This doesn't look like too bad a place to start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/iphlp/ip-helper-start-page)

Comment: Appreciate if you add additional resources which might be useful for someones who never did *win32* programming.

Comment: How to call win32 from Qt?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/iphlp/managing-ip-addresses-using-addipaddress-and-deleteipaddress, it seems this will not work if application is  running by non administrator

Answer (score 0):

Instead of launching `cmd.exe` in order to invoke Powershell in order to invoke `netsh.exe` with the supplied arguments. Just invoke `netsh.exe` directly. If you do that, you can even check the process return code to see if the command succeeded.

Comment: This will led to `The requested operation requires elevation (Run as administrator)`. Running it the way its on the question pops the dialog so *Administrator* can be used temporarily just to set ip.

Comment: @KcFnMi The execution of `cmd.exe` is even on using `powershell.exe` for elevation useless here. It makes the task just more complicated because of `cmd.exe` requires a special syntax for the argument string(s) after option `/C` as described by its usage help output on running `cmd /?` in a command prompt window. That makes it really difficult to code the command line with `powershell.exe` having a different syntax than `cmd.exe` in C++ source code file and use it with `QProcess`. [QProcess::setNativeArguments](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#setNativeArguments) exists just for `cmd.exe`.